# jQuery using keydown/keyup/keypress event to fire only one time instead of multiple times when key held down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add the same div with same class after the first one on each keypress on the board.

1. Using keypress, when the user holds down the key, it causes the event to fire when its held down (and continues to run). I want to stop that and only fire the function once on a keypress even if the key is held down.

```
<div class="player1"></div>
```

```
$(document).on('keydown', function() {
    $('.player1:last').after('<div class="player1">Go!<div>');
})
```

Comment: Do you have two Questions? Or a single Question?

Comment: lol i added the second question so I wouldn't have to write whole other question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Using keypress, when the user holds down the key, it causes the event
>      to fire when its held down (and continues to run). I want to stop that
>      and only fire the function once on a keypress even if the key is held
>      down.

You can use `.one()` to attach `keydown` event, at `keyup` event re-attach `keydown` event using `.one()` again, which should prevent `keydown` handler from being called when key is held down.

```js
function handleKeyDown() {
    $('.player1:last').after('<div class="player1">Go!<div>');
}

var d = $(document);

d.one('keydown', handleKeyDown)
.on("keyup", function() {
  d.one("keydown", handleKeyDown)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="player1"></div>
```